# How to avoid login with an empty password field in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, html-helper

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project where I have created a customized login and registration page. The application is working fine, but the problem is I am able to login even when my password field is empty.

Here is the code for controller(I used all Namespaces and reference correctly)

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Register/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Models.Register userr)
    {
        if (IsValid(userr.Email_Id, userr.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userr.Email_Id, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }

        return View(userr);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Models.Register user)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new MvcApplication2.Models.OnlineEducationEntities())
                {

                    var newUser = db.Registers.Create();
                    newUser.Email_Id = user.Email_Id;
                    newUser.Password = user.Password;
                    newUser.Student_Name = user.Student_Name;
                    newUser.DOB= DateTime.Now;

                    db.Registers.Add(newUser);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "User");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is not correct");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            throw;
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "User");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
        bool IsValid = false;

        using (var db = new MvcApplication2.Models.OnlineEducationEntities())
        {
            var user = db.Registers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email_Id == email);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.Password))
                {
                    IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return IsValid;
    }   
}
```

And the is my view:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Register
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email_Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email_Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email_Id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
 < div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "Register")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Comment: Just add a `[Required]` attribute to your `Password` property

Comment: Thanks you again but yes, I have add [Required] properly still not working.

Comment: What is not working? If you have added that attribute you wont even be able to submit the form, and `ModelState` would be invalid even if you disabled client side validation so you would not be saving it (use `if (ModelState.IsValid)`. and if its not, return the view)

Comment: The problem is that it is checking for email id but if you leave the password field empty and submitting the form, it is allowing to do so. If both email and password are empty then it is showing required, but allow user to enter in the system.I think IsValid method is not checking the condition for password correctly.

Comment: No ots not. Read my previous comment. You use `if(ModelState.IsValid)` and if its not then you return the view (not save your data). `ModelState` will not be valid if you have the `[Required]` attribute and you post an empty value. Use the features of the framework, not your `IsValid` method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this check to your `IsValid` method:

```
private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || password.Length < 6)
        return false;

    //... etc.
```

The problem is, since you are  not using `ModelState.IsValid`, you'll need an alternative. Your `IsValid` method seems to be that alternative.